# Window phone Application run time error

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, smartphone, silverlight-5.0

I've Started developing Windows Phone application. Creating a new project causes the exception below to appear. I don't know what the problem might be. Can anyone help?

```
System.InvalidProgramException
Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute..ctor(Type type)
   at MS.Internal.Metadata.IntrinsicMetadata.AddTypeConverterAttributes()
   at MS.Internal.Metadata.IntrinsicMetadata.get_CustomAttributes()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.SilverlightMetadataContext..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.SilverlightMetadataContext..ctor(DesignerPlatform platformFactory, Platform blendPlatform)
   at MS.Internal.Platform.SilverlightPlatformImpl.get_MetadataContext()
   at MS.Internal.Platform.SlmPlatformImpl.get_MetadataContext()
   at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.RemoteReferenceProxy.EnsurePlatformInitialized()
   at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.RemoteReferenceProxy.EnsurePlatformInitialized()
   at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.CreateIsolationProvider(String originalIdentifier, Boolean isGlobal, String identity, FrameworkName frameworkName, AssemblyName appAssemblyName, IVsHierarchy hierarchy)
   at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.CreateIsolationProviderWorker(String identifier, IServiceProvider provider)
   at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.CreateIsolationProvider(String identifier, IServiceProvider provider)
   at MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.CreateIsolationProvider(IServiceProvider provider, IVsHierarchy hierarchy)
   at MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Initialize>b__0(IsolationProviderProxy i)
   at MS.Internal.Providers.IsolationProviderProxy.get_RealProvider()
   at MS.Internal.Providers.IsolationProviderProxy.add_UnhandledException(UnhandledExceptionEventHandler value)
   at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()
```

Comment: Can you provide more details such as your environment, whether you are using a device or emulator, which of the project templates you are using, etc

Comment: sorry for late reply :(  I am Using emulator(windows phone emulator 7). i got the solution for the mention problem. i have re-installed all the software and later it got work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've also had such a situation, so i just installed MS Visual Studio service pack 1 and Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 Update and now it works:)
i've seen another solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-CN/visualstudio2010zhchs/thread/397fc399-8277-40c4-b0a4-63abbb29cc95), it didn't help me, however it may help someone else.